# Query simple XDocument in LINQ

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm probably doing something realy stupid but I cant get this to work:

```
var xmlQuery = from i in doc.Descendants("Item")
  select new TriggerItem()
  {
  CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
  ItemIdentifier = i.Attribute("itemCode").Value,
  Name = i.Attribute("name").Value,
  ProductIdentifier = (i.Attribute("productCode") != null) ? i.Attribute("productCode").Value : null
  };
```

doc is an Xdocument object, which when debugging, i can confirm it has loaded the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Items xmlns="http://mywebsite">
<Item itemCode="12345" productCode="" name="testing" categoryId="">
</Item>
</Items>
```

so xmlQuery.Count() shud return 1, as one Item in ther, but it keeps returning 0!

iv also tried:

```
xmlQuery = from i in doc.Descendants("Items")
```

and

```
xmlQuery = from i in doc.Descendants("Item")
```

Even without creating a new TriggerItem object, it won't return anything ...any ideas?? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know XML so I can tell you that the Item element is in the "http://activepromotion.net/Data/TriggerItems/1.0" namespace, but you're searching for it in the default namespace.

I don't know LINQ to XML well enough to tell you how to do that, though.

Comment: Thanks so much, I removed the xmlns attrbute and it worked, where does this xmlns actually go? Or does it even need to be there? All I want to do in this xml is tell it where it the XSD is placed and keep it unique

Comment: The page at http://tempuri.org/ gives a good explanation of what an XML namespace is for, and provides links to more information. Don't be put off by the fact that the page talks about web services.

Answer (score 8):

You need to specify the namespace, something like....

```
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("yourURI");
var qry = from i in doc.Descendants(ns + "Items")....
```